# How to get all fields of selected features in C#

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, features

I am looking for a way to get all selected features from a map which belongs to a specific feature class (shapefile, geo database,…).

To be more specific and to give you a real case for my question: I want check if the feature class of selected feature has a special field. If this is the case I want to get the value of this field from the selected feature and add this value into a combobox. This process should be repeated for all selected features.

I tried the following but it crashed with an object reference error.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
IMap Pmap = doc.FocusMap;
IEnumFeature pEnumFeat = (IEnumFeature)Pmap.FeatureSelection;
pEnumFeat.Reset();
IFields fields;
try
{
  IFeature pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();
  while (pfeat != null)
  {
    fields = pfeat.Fields;
    int x = fields.FindField("ID_K");
    if (!x.Equals(-1))
    {
      list.Add(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString());
    }
    pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found a solution. Here is the working code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
IMap Pmap = doc.FocusMap;
IEnumFeature pEnumFeat = (IEnumFeature)Pmap.FeatureSelection;
IFields fields;
pEnumFeat.Reset();
IEnumFeatureSetup enumFeatSetup = (IEnumFeatureSetup)pEnumFeat;
enumFeatSetup.AllFields = true;
try
{
   IFeature pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();

   while (pfeat != null)
   {
      fields = pfeat.Fields;
      int x = fields.FindField("ID_K");
      list.Add(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString());

      pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
```

These two line are especially important.

```
IEnumFeatureSetup enumFeatSetup = (IEnumFeatureSetup)pEnumFeat;
enumFeatSetup.AllFields = true;
```

If you don't use them you've only the shapefile included (default) and not the other fields and values.

Comment: What line in your code does the error occur on?

Comment: pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString() ->Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Just a thought, as I'm not very familiar with arcobjects, but is get_Value() looking for a field object and not just an index integer?  So instead of get_Value(x) would get_Value(fields[x]) do anything?

Comment: get_Value needs an integer for the index of the field.

Comment: What value are you getting for x?

Comment: A valid one. In my case "3".

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the value of the field isn't null? What about:

```
if (!x.Equals(-1))
{
  object value = pfeat.get_Value(x);
  list.Add(value == null ? null : value.ToString());
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to inline the null test, you could always do:

```
if (!x.Equals(-1))
{
  object value = pfeat.get_Value(x);
  if(value != null)
  {
    list.Add(value.ToString());
  }
  else
  {
    list.Add(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, for all elements in the feature class the field is set with a valid value.

Comment: Huh, I might be stumped then. From the error and the line number, there's a limited number of things that could be null. "list" certainly isn't, but I don't see how "pfeat" could be.